# WordPress set user firstname and lastname as navigation link name

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress

Today I've asked myself "How can I set the current users firstname and lastname to a menu item in WordPress?". So I've tried a bit and just ask this question because I want to share my solution with you! I hope it helps you sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the current user firstname and lastname (or any other value) to your navigation, you first need to add a placeholder to the menu link title in you `Menu` settings. In my case it's `{user_name}`:

[image]

---

When you got this done, save the menu and open your themes `functions.php` file. Now I've some code for you. Copy it into your `functions.php` file save it and upload it to your server:

```
/**
 * Set user firstname and lastname into navigation
 */
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'set_navigation_user_name' );
function set_navigation_user_name( $menu_items ) {
    foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if ( '{user_name}' === $menu_item->title ) {
            //Get user and his name
            $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
            $user_firstname = $current_user->user_firstname;
            $user_lastname  = $current_user->user_lastname;

            $menu_item->title = $user_firstname . ' ' . $user_lastname;
        }
    }

    return $menu_items;
}
```

---

You can set any possible value to your placeholder. For example when you want to set the users email to this placeholder, you can do this:

```
$menu_item->title = $current_user->user_email;
```